# React: image loading but not displaying

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am creating a web application with react.
Currently I am trying to create cards that contain header text and an image.

My current problem is that when I import the image and try to use it like this:

```
import iwatch from './images/iwatch.jpg';
...
<img src = {iwatch} />
```

the image seems to appear but is displayed as 0x0.
I am able to use css' background-image to get around this but creating css classes for each card is not the route I would like to take.

I read every post with the same issue as mine and attempted all solutions listed but nothing ever seemed to work.

Problem component:

```
const CategorySelectionContainer = () => {

  const categories = [
    {
      name: "Cell Phone",
    },
    {
      name: "Tablet",
    },
    {
      name: "Smart Watch",
    }
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <div class = 'container'>
        <h2 class = 'center-text'>
          <strong>
            Select a device to get started.
          </strong>
        </h2>
        <div class = 'justify'>
        {categories.map((cat) =>
          <div key = {cat.name} class = 'card card-2 center-text card-container'>
            <div class = 'image'>
              <h4>{cat.name}</h4>
              <img style={{width:'auto',height:'auto'}} class = 'img' url = '/images/iwatch.jpg'/ >
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CategorySelectionContainer
```

currently the image is in the public folder which is why i just reference the image without any curly braces.

I tried:

1. Importing the image relative to the js file (as seen above)
2. Moving the image to the public folder to reference it that way

I have a feeling it is something css related but I just have no idea what could be wrong.
edit: I am able to use the  in the app component and it displays correctly. Still not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you have pasted in, you have used `url` to give the image tag a source link, please use `src`.

Another thing, use className instead of class.

```js
<img style={{width:'auto',height:'auto'}} className='img' src='/images/iwatch.jpg'/ >
```

To get this work, the '/images/iwatch.jpg' needs to be in the right place, otherwise you can use the imported one like

```js
<img style={{width:'auto',height:'auto'}} className='img' src={iwatch} / >
```

Comment: and thats why I shouldnt be programming at 1 in the morning. Thanks!
what difference does className bring?

Comment: React js reserves the keyword `class`, you need to use `className`, eventually react will turn into class anyway.